# Grails build error

Tags: grails

I am getting the following error message from an app which I inherited. I do not have experience with grails/groovy and I have no idea where to add "--stacktrace"?
I have checked the BuilConfig.groovy file and I do not see a place where javac is called.

Please help.

```
Error loading plugin manager: Cannot get property 'file' on null object (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: you add it to your `grails <something> --stacktrace` call

Comment: Are you using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying Java 8, this issue occur You can try using java7 and it will work fine! Apparently grails does not work with java8 .

Comment: No, I am using java 7

Comment: Newer versions of Grails work fine with Java 8, in particular 2.4.x